# May I put leaflet plugin *.js and *.css together?

Tags: javascript, plugins, leaflet

sorry, dummy. I use some leaflet *.js plugins with the additional *.css. So each of my *.html has a lot of additional lines in the head.
May I copy the *.js together in one file, the *.css too?
I found something about compressing with gzip, but this works only for a single file. Can I find someware dokumentation on that?
What about copyrights?

Gruss, wonk

Answer (score 0):

You can use [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) to bundle your CSS and js files.

Answer (score 0):

you could put the link to the cdn(that thing you put to use them in the beginning) and then make all other web pages extend that original master page